# Get title Attribute of input variable using PHP

Tags: php, forms, input, title

How to get div's title attribute in php. I want to get the title value like "Hong Kong (香港): +852" in php. There is any way to parse this information.

```
<div class="selected-flag" role="combobox" aria-owns="country-listbox" tabindex="0" title="Hong Kong (香港): +852"></div>
```

Comment: If you already have it in PHP, you can achieve this. If not, you can't with PHP alone. Pick it by JS and send it to PHP with Ajax.

Comment: Are you getting this tag as a string? Or how do you get this data in php?

Comment: get it using jQuery then store in hidden input

Comment: Is possible to get the title data using php?

Comment: maybe DOM will help u here